# How do I force an onclick event to load throughout the lifecycle of a page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, onclick

I have an onClick event on a button that is created using data returned from the server (via Ajax). The outline of my code is this:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function() {
$.ajax({
    url: '/',
    dataType: 'json', 
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    data: textInput,
    success: function (response) {
        if(response.error_code!=null){
            alert(response.user_message);
        }
        else {
         //code to generate button with id tag `cvResults`

         $('#cvResults').click(function(e) {
         // some code here, redirects to another mobile page
        }
        },//then remainder of ajax function
```

I initially tried putting the onClick function outside the Ajax call (but within the `pageinit`). This wouldn't trigger because the page would initiate without any `#cvResults` tags and hence not load the function.

I now have a different problem. When you click this button and go to the other page, if you then press `back` and try to click the button again, the event isn't triggered. This makes sense because there has been no response from Ajax.

How do I cater for both of these scenarios, and just permanently have the onClick event listening when the `#cvResults` tag is present?

Answer (score 1):

Try this method to bind any click events for dynamically created elements.

```
$('document').on('click','#cvResults',function(){
    // your code.
})
```

Since your page init without this element the event will not bind if you do it in the regular way.

Comment: This is not correct. The delegation syntax is `$(document).on('click', '#cvResults', function...);`

Comment: Changed the syntax.!

Comment: Thanks guys. Where do I put this function? I have just tried it 1) outside of the existing onInit 2) within the Ajax Success Call 3) within the document onInit but outside of the Ajax function. Neither triggered the function upon clicking the function.